# SQLITE inner join windows phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, join, windows-phone-8

I  have  two  tables... ITEM  and  STOREITEM

```
 ITEM columns --ITMID_PK,ITMNAME, description ,iCON

STOREITEM columns   --ITMID_FK,PRICE
```

to retrieve  data of ITEM table  to  list and  store  in  listbox. I  follow this

```
List<ITEM> retrievedlist = sqlconn.query<ITEM>("select * from ITEM").ToList<ITEM>();

  foreach (var t in retrievedlist )
       {

           listbox.Items.Add(t);
       }
```

this  works  perfectly  for  single  table

Now
I  need  to  perform  INNER  JOIN in  code behind(c#) for  this  two  tables..

what  i  have  tried is..

```
List<STOREITEM> retrievedlist = sqlconn.Query<STOREITEM>("select ITEM.ITMNAME,ITEM.ICON,STOREITEM.PRICE FROM ITEM INNER JOIN  STOREITEM  ON ITEM.ITMID_PK=STOREITEM.ITMID_FK ORDER BY ITMNAME").ToList<STOREITEM>();
```

it  returns only  STOREITEM based  columns  ,as  we  are  giving  STOREITEM besides  query method..

so  i tried  this  too

```
 List<ITEM> retrievedlist = sqlconn.Query<ITEM>("select ITEM.ITMNAME,ITEM.ICON,STOREITEM.PRICE FROM ITEM INNER JOIN  STOREITEM  ON ITEM.ITMID_PK=STOREITEM.ITMID_FK ORDER BY ITMNAME").ToList<ITEM>();
```

it  returns only  ITEM  based  columns...  even though  query method..  has INNER  join query

the  following  one  wont  work  ,as  it  has  invalid  parameters in  Query method(two  table  names  given as  class inside  query<>)

```
    List<ITEM,STOREITEM> retrievedlist = sqlconn.Query<ITEM>("select ITEM.ITMNAME,ITEM.ICON,STOREITEM.PRICE FROM ITEM INNER JOIN  STOREITEM  ON ITEM.ITMID_PK=STOREITEM.ITMID_FK ORDER BY ITMNAME").ToList<ITEM>();
```

please  help me  with  this..
the queried  data should  be  stored in  list  and  then  that list should  added  as  items  to  listbox..
any  help  is  appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class which has properties from both the class and use that classes. In your case it will have ITMID_PK,ITMNAME, description ,iCON and PRICE. Just keep the properties name same as column name. That class can be a separate class or Base class for these two classes.

Edit: You can create a class like this

```
 public class Class1
{
    public string ITMID_PK { get; set; }
    public string ITMNAME { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string iCON { get; set; }
    public string PRICE { get; set; }

}
```

Modify query to:

```
List<Class1> retrievedlist = sqlconn.Query<Class1>("select ITEM.ITMNAME,ITEM.ICON,STOREITEM.PRICE FROM ITEM INNER JOIN STOREITEM ON ITEM.ITMID_PK=STOREITEM.ITMID_FK ORDER BY ITMNAME").ToList<Class1>();
```

Comment: to populate  that  new  class..  i  need  to  write  similar query   as  mentioned  above.. @Nishi

Comment: It will be same with just class name changed:  List<NEW_CLASS> retrievedlist = sqlconn.Query<ITEM>("select ITEM.ITMNAME,ITEM.ICON,STOREITEM.PRICE FROM ITEM INNER JOIN  STOREITEM  ON ITEM.ITMID_PK=STOREITEM.ITMID_FK ORDER BY ITMNAME").ToList<ITEM>();

Comment: i  need  to  get  a  column  from STOREITEM  too...  the  query  u  mentioned  returns  only  columns  of  ITEM Table.....

Comment: No, You are querying for PRICE also but because your ITEM class does not have PRICE field you cannot see the return value. So your new class should have all the columns you are fetching.

Comment: how  you  gonna populate  the  new  class ..this  class  should  have   columns  of  both  ITEM  &  STOREITEM....

Comment: updated my answer. You can have a class in you project like this and use List<class1> to get results.

Comment: you  are  thniking   about  only left  side of  equation...what  about  the  right side..  as  query method  have  only  one  table  allowed..how  u  gonna  save  both  tables  data  to    the  new  class..

Comment: try this and let me know what error you are getting.

Comment: tried..it  returns  only  the  tbale  columns which  we  gave  on  right  side

Comment: modify query to- List<NEW_CLASS> retrievedlist = sqlconn.Query<ITEM>("select ITEM.ITMNAME,ITEM.ICON,STOREITEM.PRICE FROM ITEM INNER JOIN STOREITEM ON ITEM.ITMID_PK=STOREITEM.ITMID_FK ORDER BY ITMNAME").ToList<NEW_CLASS>();

Comment: it showing  error  as   class  new_class    not  matching  with  ITEM  class  of  query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80276/discussion-between-kartiikeya-and-nishi).

Comment: it  worked...  tq..                                                                       List<NEW_CLASS> retrievedlist = sqlconn.Query<NEW_CLASS>("select ITEM.ITMNAME,ITEM.ICON,STOREITEM.PRICE FROM ITEM INNER JOIN STOREITEM ON ITEM.ITMID_PK=STOREITEM.ITMID_FK ORDER BY ITMNAME").ToList<NEW_CLASS>();

Answer (score 0):

try  ..this  ..it  works..

```
List<NEW_CLASS> retrievedlist = sqlconn.Query<NEW_CLASS>("select ITEM.ITMNAME,ITEM.ICON,STOREITEM.PRICE FROM ITEM INNER JOIN STOREITEM ON ITEM.ITMID_PK=STOREITEM.ITMID_FK ORDER BY ITMNAME").ToList<NEW_CLASS>();
```

Comment: Although this might answer the question and code-only answers are allowed, you should include comments in your code and/or include an additional explanation to improve your answer and make it clearer for the SO community.